# android.nfc.tech.NfcV what does mean the byte return by getResponseFlags?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I have to do an application in NFC. My tag return NFC-V, so I cast it in NfcV. And I have to extract some information, and the method `getResponseFlags` seems contains what I need. But I didn't find any documentation that explains me how read the returned byte. I suppose it is a bitwise of several properties, but in witch order and witch information, it is no where explains.
Where I can get information about this?

PS: I have already searched Google with lot of request, I have also looked in source code and in javadoc, I have also read some PDF about ISO 15693 (NFC-V), but nothing says me for example the bit 5 means "is Afi Locked" (Its just an example, probably not the truth)

Comment: I have found finally a document the explains what is it, I post here the address off th document in case that somebody search the same thing :
 http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Finternet%2Fcom%2FTECHNICAL_RESOURCES%2FTECHNICAL_LITERATURE%2FAPPLICATION_NOTE%2FCD00266055.pdf&rct=j&q=ISO15693%20RFU&ei=l10ITsDfJoWRswbFwqzoBg&usg=AFQjCNHSL-c2lsdKeMio-l1nF7VSRl2FFA&sig2=AOpu0glhXn8TLnBtUh9nZg&cad=rja (Page 6)
Regards,
JHelp
Sorry for puting this in comments not in answer, but the site don't let me do it

Answer (score 1):

You need the ISO15639-3 spec (note the '3') - that one details the required commands & defines the responses, including the bitmasks for the relevant fields.

The response-flags returned by only contain an error-flag (bit 0), and a flag to indicate if there are extensions to the protocol (bit 4). To get information about DSFID, AFI, etc you'll need to use the 'Get System Information' command ('2B')

To get the spec you'll need to pay the ISO organisation 150CHF :-(, but a bit of googleing should find you alternative sources.

Note that RFID-manufacturers can add extra commands to the protocol. For those you'll have to consult the datasheets.